# How to show a function is $C^1$? (apart from showing continuity partial derivatives)

Tags: derivatives, continuity

As of now, the only way I know to show that a function $f\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^k$ is $C^1$ at $\vec a\in\mathbb R^n$, is by showing its partial derivatives $D_if_j(\vec a)$ are continuous. Are there any other ways?

Comment: Composition, product and sum of $C^1$ functions are also $C^1$. That's how to best approach a function like $f(x, y) = e^{x^2 -\sin(x+y)}\ln(\cos(y) + 3)$.

Comment: Fancy way: Sobolev embedding theorems.

Comment: Well that is the definition. And any result that looks different than using the definition is a result in which the definition was used.

Comment: @zhw. No, the definition of a differentiable is one which is possible to approximate linearly. Continuous partial derivatives is a theorem using that definition.

Comment: @Arthur I guess it depends on where you grew up. Certainly when $k=1$ it is quite often defined in the way I said. When $k>1$ you may be right, although I didn't see it defined that way initially.

Comment: @ zhw. There are differentiable functions without continuous (partial) derivatives. In other words,  there is concrete reason for the class $C^1$ of functions to be called _continuously_ differentiable. For instance,  for $k=1$, the function given by $x\mapsto x^{-2}\sin (1/x) $ for $x\neq0$ and $0\mapsto0$ is differentiable, but its derivative is discontinuous. However, if the (partial) derivatives are continuous, then the function is differentiable.

Comment: @zhw. And now I see that the question is actually about $C^1$ and not differentiable functions. So I was wrong and now agree with you.